# Xcode 6.3 Swift Autocompletion

Tags: xcode, swift

I just upgraded to the final release of Xcode 6.3, and found that the autocompletion for Swift code is totally nonfunctional. Sometimes, I cannot get the autocompletion popup to appear at all (even when I mash <kbd>Esc</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl+Space</kbd>). Other times, the autocompletion popup appears, but it does not provide context-sensitive completion suggestions, only “every word that appears in this file” completion (which, by the way, drives me stir-crazy). Autocompletion in Objective-C files works just fine.

I have tried removing my `DerivedData` folder, deleting the `xcuserdata` folders from inside the project package, removing the `~/Library/Caches/com.apple.dt.Xcode` directory, and rebooting; none of these procedures has produced a change in Xcode’s behavior.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing I did was to delete the derived data directories in
~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData. That didn’t fix it.

So, how to open Xcode and have it not reopen any projects that it had open?
It seems there are a few ways.

If Xcode is in your dock, you can option-shift click on it and it won’t open any projects.

Or, you can get rid of all your autosave info like this.

yes | rm -r ~/Library/Autosave\ Information/

yes | rm -r ~/Library/Saved\ Application\State/com.apple.dt.Xcode.savedState

Finally, you can open Xcode from the command line with this incantation.

open -a /Applications/Xcode.app --args -ApplePersistenceIgnoreState YES

Comment: I don't _quite_ understand what you’re suggesting, but it didn’t work anyway.